# How to stream data to a sails socket from a sail waterline model?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sockets, sails.js, node-streams

I'm following the simple example given in the [Sails documentation](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/stream)

```
// Start the stream.  Pipe it to sockets.
User.stream({name:'Walter'}).pipe(req.socket.emit);
```

I hit this error

```
TypeError: dest.on is not a function
    at Stream.pipe
```

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: `getSocket` is likely incorrect. Are you calling this API via socket from browser properly?

Comment: `getSocket` is `req.socket`

Comment: Great. How is request being made?

Comment: Request is a sails socket

Comment: Is this in a controller endpoint that receives a proper HTTP or Socket request, and are you doing the `req.isSocket` check recommended?

Comment: Yeah. Actually the issue seems to be with the version of sails-mysql-transactions I am using. It has not yet been updated to support streaming of responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [sails-mysql-transactions](https://github.com/postmanlabs/sails-mysql-transactions-waterline) as the adapter. Currently this does not support the `.stream()` method.